# The AnimateWindow caused my controls border not render. Why?

Tags: c#, winforms

I use a code for animate form at winfom c#
like this:

```
public static extern bool AnimateWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int time, AnimateWindowFlags flags);
```

It is good work but it is caused the border of controls hidden and not show. even I create custom user control and set border in it but that did'nt show border too.
Now, What do I do?

Comment: Show us the code on how you are using it so your audience can recreate the problem.

Comment: The only animate code of above cause this problem when I remove mentioned code the problem solved but I want to use Animatewindow and controls with its borders.

Comment: All you showed was the declaration.  Show the code where you call AnimateWindow.  Which controls are losing their border?  You are missing a lot of documentation in your question.  Makes it hard to help you.

Comment: Ok, I called the declaration in Form_Load () event. This declaration cause my panels control border property set fixedsingle not displayed.

Comment: There is a way for this solve.that is "this.Refresh ()" after animate window. It's right that the border after refresh displayed but when form is loading the textboxes have border but panels no border. this problem cause the my UI present bad and not neat.

Comment: But I use that method for animate. so it is caused my panel border not show, display, render.

Comment: You did not post your code.  I re-produced the issue based on your description, and the linked answer showed the border of a panel.

Comment: No, I will not watch a video.  Edit your question with the code that reproduces the problem and someone can solve it for you.

Comment: The code not help you, the pictues or videos?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  This site does not like pictures of code, or videos.  We like code text we can copy to our machines and reproduce your issue.  Smallest amount of code that is needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you, finally I solved my problem from part code of your linked.

Comment: protected override void SetVisibleCore(bool value) {
        if (!this.IsHandleCreated) {
            NativeMethods.AnimateWindow(this.Handle, 100, AnimateWindowFlags.AW_BLEND);
        }
        base.SetVisibleCore(value);
    }

Comment: Now I have border on panels.